# Socket.io socket is getting connected but not emitting event using express and react.js

Tags: reactjs, node.js, express, socket.io

I basically want to connect my react front-end to my express server backend. This is what I am currently doing. My react is sending the connect event which is getting handled in the server. Yet if I emit any event from the react app its corresponding handler is not getting called in the back end.

This is my react and server code.

**My react code**

```
import React, { useEffect, useState, useRef } from "react"
import { io } from 'socket.io-client';

function useSocket(url) {
    const [socket, setSocket] = useState(null)

    useEffect(() => {
        const socketIo = io(url, {
            reconnectionDelayMax: 10000,
            autoConnect: false,
            transports: ['websocket'],
            cors: {
                origin: "http://127.0.0.1:8000/"

            }
        }).connect();


        setSocket(socketIo)

        function cleanup() {
            socketIo.disconnect()
        }
        return cleanup

 
    }, [])

    return socket
}

function thiscomp() {


    // const videoRef = useRef(null);
    // const canvasRef = useRef(null);
    const socket = useSocket('http://127.0.0.1:8000/')

    useEffect(() => {
        if (socket) {
            socket.emit('msg')
        }
    }, [socket])

    return (
        <>
            <div>
                


            </div>
        </>
    )
}

export default thiscomp
```

**My server code**

```
const express = require("express")
const cors = require("cors");
const http = require('http')

const app = express()
app.use(express.json())
app.use(express.urlencoded({ extended: true }))
app.use(cors({
    origin: 'http://localhost:5173',
    credentials: true,
}))

const server = http.createServer(app)
const { Server } = require('socket.io')
const io = new Server(server)

io.on('connect', (socket) => {
    console.log('success')
})

io.on('msg',(socket)=>{
    console.log("event")
})

server.listen(8000, () => {
    console.log("port connected");
})
```

The connect event is getting emitted and the corresponding handler is printing 'success'. Yet the 'msg' event is emitted but the corresponding handler is not triggered.

Thank you for any help

Answer (score 1):

you should better check Socket.io documentation here https://socket.io/docs/v4/emitting-events/

If you want to work with events you should handle it like in this example:

*Server*

```
io.on("connection", (socket) => {
  socket.on("hello", (arg) => {
    console.log(arg); // world
  });
});
```

*Client*

```
socket.emit("hello", "world");
```